# How do I make my application available on the App Store only for iPhone 3G S or faster devices?

Tags: iphone, app-store, ipod

I have an app that runs slowly on an iPhone 3G but is fast enough on an iPhone 3G S.

Is there a way to limit the app to be available only for iPhone 3G S and faster devices?  I would like to avoid bad comments because 3G or even 2G users download it and then complain about it being too slow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set minimum capabilities required to use your application by providing values for the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in your application's Info.plist.  In this case, I'd recommend using the `opengles-2` capability, because all iOS devices with the post-iPhone 3G S faster hardware support OpenGL ES 2.0 and none of the ones before that do.

For more on these capabilities see Apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html).

Comment: @christian Muller - If you don't trust me, watch the Mastering OpenGL ES for iPhone - Part 2 video that is available under the advanced video track for the tech talk videos you can access in the iPhone Developer Program website.  All OpenGL ES 2.0-compatible devices are listed in that session.

Comment: brad's solution is very good, and i confirm that it works and that apple has approved an app that does this.

Comment: Would specifying armV7 instead work also ? I think it would be more clear for applications that need high performance but don't have any open GL code.