# Removing 3G from supported devices

Tags: iphone, app-store, requirements, 3g

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the iPhone 3G as a supported device for my application in the AppStore.  I emailed Apple support asking for them to update it in the reqs section and they responded saying I need to update my UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities keys.  Well, it was submitted with :

```
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
            <string>location</string>
    </array>
```

and

```
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
            <string>telephony</string>
            <string>location-services</string>
            <string>gps</string>
    </array>
```

in my plist.

Does anyone know what the exact key/value I'd need to set in order for 3G support to not be listed in the AppStore?

Comment: This question asks a similar thing: [How do I make my application available on the App Store only for iPhone 3G S or faster devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472278/how-do-i-make-my-application-available-on-the-app-store-only-for-iphone-3g-s-or-f)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to support the 3GS and the 4, you can put armv7 in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities.

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>telephony</string>
    <string>location-services</string>
    <string>gps</string>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

Comment: My only issue is that I explicitly set that my app requires background support (which it does).  Since the 3G doesn't support background tasks shouldn't that solve my problem?

Comment: I would have thought that it did - perhaps it's a bug in the way Apple checks the supported background modes.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you cannot explicitly prevent one device type from using your app. You would need to require features that the device doesn't have, but they may not be used by your application, possibly causing background and memory usage issues.