# How to declare an iPhone app which has to run in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, app-store, requirements

Hey, 
I wrote an iPhone app which needs to run in the background. I did set up the properties in my info plist according to running in the background. The problem is that the app store lists iPhone 3G as well as "compatible device".

Is it possible to set up my info plist to get rid of the iPhone 3G in the app store?

I found one solution by adding 'opengles-2' to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities - but it doesnt seem like the best way to do it?!

Thanks!

Comment: what is the reason that you can't make an app that is available for all devices but uses its background functions only where available? Like everyone else does it.

Comment: My app's functionality relies on the background services. The app does not make any sense if it's not capable of running in the background. The problem is: it appears to the user like the app "works" but it's really not. which causes pretty bad reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't discriminate directly on actual device types (3G versus iPhone 4 etc.), but as you note things in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities may imply certain devices. <strike>However, there's a more direct route, read on...</strike>

<strike>If you require multitasking compatible devices, that would be any device running iOS4 or higher. There's a setting in your XCode project's build settings that allows you to set the minimum required iOS for your app to run -- "iOS Deployment Target". Set this to "iOS4" and your app will only be available to multitasking enabled iDevices (which includes iPad with iOS4 or higher, btw).</strike> -- no, not enough, see comments below and Jules' link.

Comment: Btw, I take it you know that iOS 'multitasking' is very limited in what it allows you to multitask? Things like VOIP and streaming audio are ok, but general multitasking/backgrounding isn't possible.

Comment: but it's not enough just to check for iOS4 because iPhone 3G runs iOS 4 as well - just without the background multitasking capabilities.

Comment: just found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128165/removing-3g-from-supported-devices) but what happens if there is an armv8 architecture?