# Can a restrict my app to iPhone 3GS/iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, performance, submission

I have an app which runs excellently on an iPhone 4, and comfortably on a 3GS.  Is it possible to target only the 3GS/4 and **not** the 3G?  The 3G just freaks out when I run it, all sorts of graphical glitches, crashing, low fps etc, I don't even want 3G users to see the app on the store.  I can't really 'tone down' the app to use less memory/power for the 3G, it would remove the main purpose of the app.

The only way I have come up with is to adding multitasking as a requirement for the app in the info.plist, but this seems a little hacky.

Also, is this likely to get me in trouble as far as submission goes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make my application available on the App Store only for iPhone 3G S or faster devices? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472278/how-do-i-make-my-application-available-on-the-app-store-only-for-iphone-3g-s-or-f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "armv7" to the required device capabilities of your app's info.plist.  Only the 3GS and newer use that CPU architecture.  An app requiring armv7 won't even install on a 3G and other older armv6 devices.

Comment: How about all versions of iPod Touch, iPad etc? Do they all work with armv7?

Comment: Also I noted that when building Release versions, it (the compiler) warns/complains about the *required* armv6 binary is not selected. So, the question is whether armv6 is really required or not for submitting to the app store...

Comment: If armv7 is in the plist as a device requirement, any armv6 binary may not even need to work since it can't even be installed to test on any actual customer armv6 device.

Comment: I just noticed that armv7 is NOT compatible with iPod Touch, I think 2nd generation. The generation from last year (with retina screen) would be compatible I assume however.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been addressed previously, you can determine the version and perform an appropriate action based on that.

[Link to thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543925/how-do-i-detect-whether-i-have-iphone-2g-3g-3gs/1546070#1546070)

Comment: But this won't prevent someone with unsupported hardware from buying the app.