# Target iPhone application by model (e.g. 3G vs 3GS)

Tags: iphone, ios, device, target

Much like the required device capabilities on the info.plist file, is it possible to configure an application such that it will only be available on some device models?

I know how to target it by device family (iPhone&iPod vs iPad), but in this case I'm looking to target by model. I also know how to programmatically determine the model, but what I want is for iTunes to prevent some device models from being able to download an app, which is why doing it via info.plist seems like it would be the best way.

For instance, if I wanted an app to be available on iPhone 3GS (or iPhone/iPod 4) and upper but NOT on iPhone 3G, is there any way to do it?

Comment: This question gets asked every 1/2 hour today.

Comment: Hm? Didn't see it anywhere...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make my application available on the App Store only for iPhone 3G S or faster devices? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472278/how-do-i-make-my-application-available-on-the-app-store-only-for-iphone-3g-s-or-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it, except in code. Apple discourages it, instead asking you to require specific features instead of specific models.

The best you can do is note in the product description that not all features are available/performant on the 3G hardware, for example, and then disable those features in code or let them run poorly.

Comment: Too bad.

For what I wanted, checking it in code was no good (I didn't want iPhone 3G users buying the app only to find that it would crash on startup).

Fortunately we managed to fix the issue that was causing the crash so this will no longer be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3)

Comment: Further hint: 3GS has a magnetometer. 3G doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I had previously looked at this list but didn't notice that one.

Comment: Furthermore ... 3GS supports OpenGL ES  2 ...3G doesn't ;)

Answer (score 2):

Put armv7 in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities of the app's info.plist.  That will prevent an app from loading on an iPhone 3G, which uses the armv6 processor architecture.

Comment: I found out that that will also stop iPod Touches of 2nd generation. So it's a no go if iPhone 3G is all you want to exclude (like me).