# AppStore submission devices

Tags: iphone, app-store, retina-display

We have in store an app which displays a series of videos through HTTP Live Streaming. Due to the nature of this videos, and the screensize of the iPhone/iPod device, we have decided to leave behind everything that does not have retina display.
The reason? Well, this videos are encoded in high resolution, and even that we have encoded them in lower resolution, those videos are still a bit pixelated. Since is is a paid app, we don't want to charge iPhone 3G/s users for an app they're not gonna enjoy at most.

The problem now is that we have decided to make the app universal, so iPad users can enjoy the app without that crappy upscaling from emulation. The problem goes like this.

In order to leave behind iPhone 3G/s users from buying the app, we have set as required the front facing camera, but we do not use it, of course. Why? front facing camera = retina display ;) . The problem is with the iPad. We can do the same with the iPad 2, but not with the iPad 1.

So the question is...is there anyway so we can submit the app to be available to everyone except iPhone 3G/s (or iPod)??

Comment: Why not allow the older devices? So they won't look quite as good--who cares? Users of older devices know their screens aren't 326dpi, but they don't mind.

Comment: Even if you're supposed to know it won't look as good or whether or not your device has a retina display (or even what a retina display is), most users will buy it anyway and then complain if it doesn't look good -> which leads to bad reviews -> which is bad.

Comment: Btw, just to check, are you planning on doing this on an upgrade of the existing app (as opposed to a new app)? Are you sure you can do that? I thought you couldn't change the app requirements... (or maybe it's just the target SDK that you can't "increase").

Comment: Seems you're right André. I can decrease the requirements, but not include anymore. So I guess we'll have to make the app available to everyone or just leave behind iPad 1. We do not want to make an HD version for iPad only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put constraints on the App in the store, informing of the need for retina display or whatever device capability it needs (i.e., Camera [not on old iPod Touch], GPS, etc.).  It does lead to bad reviews, but you cannot stop idiots in the world from buying a product.  There have been plenty of cases brought to court where the plantiff is suing a home owner for being injured while breaking in or robbing the house and they won...I mean really?...don't let users who don't have common sense deter you from putting out a product.

Comment: Guess you're right. Your last sentence is SOOO RIGHTT. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To [drop the iPhone 3G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268560/target-iphone-application-by-model-e-g-3g-vs-3gs), you could add the magnometer as a required capability.

That still doesn't take care of the 3GS though...

Answer (score 0):

You can make your app Universal, while maintaining the requirements. You should check two things:

1. The device is an iPad/iPad 2?
2. If not, does it have a camera?

Merging these two tests you can determine if the app is running on an iPad (2) or on a retina-display-powered device. It will just require a couple of lines of code more. Eg. test for:

```
UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

Comment: Yeah I know. But it's not a code issue, it's more app store related.

Comment: I thought you were putting constraints in the code, not merely in the App Store... sorry!